# sliderDown not working - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please,  why this Jquery doesn't Working

```
$(function(){
    $('.accContainer').hide();
    $('.accordion:first').next().slideDown("");

    $('.accordion').click(function(){
    if( $(this).next().is(':hidden') ) {
            $('.accordion').next().slideUp();
            $(this).next().slideDown();
        }
        return false; 
    });
});
```

code : http://www.jsfiddle.net/BQYQ5/22

Answer (score 3):

You aren't closing `h2`:

Change:

```
<h2 class="accordion"><a href="">-... </a><h2>
```

To:

```
<h2 class="accordion"><a href="">-... </a></h2>
```

[See updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BQYQ5/23/)

Comment: +1... I am turning in my StackOverflow card for the day.

Answer (score 0):

A better option than the code you have may be instead to use [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), as what you have now won't allow you to close a tab that is opened. It will also simplify your code quite a bit.

```
$('.accordion').click(function(){
    $(this).next().toggle();
    return false; 
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZFTk4/)